# Check all the records in core data iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have from .NET platform and been familiar with querying databases and watching the records in a tabular format. Here in iOS Core Data is there any way to watch all the records of the entity. I am unable to feel comfortable just by imagining.

any ideas?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with them. Do you just want to pull them into an array? Are you displaying them in a table view?

Comment: Are you looking for SQL debug modes?

Comment: i just want to see them just for my reference. if i update any records.

Comment: Actually fetching is easier but you can use this to see the db. [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Comment: There are apps that allow access to the database during development, "Base - SQLite Editor" available in the Apple App store is one that I use.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all objects for a given entity description like this...

For instance if you want to get all `Person` objects...

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];

NSArray *allPersons = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

// allPersons will now contain all the Person objects stored in Core Data
```

But this is the tip of the iceberg in terms of what you can do.

For instance if you wish to display the Person objects in a tableview then you wouldn't do this. You'd create an `NSFetchedResultsController` and use that as a datasource for your table. This caches results and minimises memory usage for when you have thousands of results.

Comment: i don't want to show the records anywhere . just for my understanding want to look.

Answer (score 1):

> in iOS Core Data is there any way to watch all the records of the entity

Sure. There are at least two options:

1. If you just want to see how it all works, you can examine the SQLite database file that's used as a data store. Use the `sqlite3` command line tool for this, or one of the database front ends like MesaSQLite. There are some ground rules: 1) don't change the database directly; 2) don't make any assumptions about how Core Data uses SQLite; 3) try not to think about your Core Data data store in terms of tables and records.
2. If you want to keep an eye on the items stored in your data store, consider building a simple table-based interface into your app. You can include it only in your debug builds. Create a subclass of UITableViewController that uses a NSFetchedResultsController to pull the data. There's example code in [the NSFetchedResultsController docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).